How to establish a consistent hash ring with 300 million virtual nodes within 10 seconds with C++
As stated in the title I received an optimization task. I want to create a hash ring but I need to add too many virtual nodes on it(Distributed storage requirements), and I hope the entire establishment time does not exceed 10 seconds or shorter better. The current logic is to loop as many times as there are virtual nodes and store their information in the std::map, which is a very time-consuming approach.
I tried using multithreading to separate loop operations, but it didn't work or even slower !If there are available open-source implementations or good suggestions, I would be very grateful!

It is hard to help you more with so few information. I expect network operation to be the expensive part and it is very dependent of the target kind of distributed structure. Do you mean distributed hash rings like Chord?

std::map is not a hash map but a tree-based data-structure (RB-tree in practice). If you want a hash-based data structure, then you should use std::unordered_map instead. There are faster hash map if you do not care about iterator invalidation (but they are not provided by the STL).

I have tried std::unordered_map, it did indeed play a role, but in previous logic, when searching for a node on a ring, the method used was map.lower_bound(approaching a point), which is not contained in the unordered_map
